# process started by systemd does not see environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, systemd

I have the following system file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Let's Encrypt renewal

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=AWS_CONFIG_FILE='/etc/letsencrypt/aws_creds_prod.ini'
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet --agree-tos --noninteractive
```

When it runs, the route-53-plugin complains that it can't find any config values.

If I do `AWS_CONFIG_FILE='/etc/letsencrypt/aws_creds_prod.ini' /usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet --agree-tos --noninteractive` in the commandline, it works.

If I create a service file looking like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Environment Test

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=AWS_CONFIG_FILE='/etc/letsencrypt/aws_creds_prod.ini'
ExecStart=-/bin/echo $AWS_CONFIG_FILE
```

I get the entry `Apr 13 09:35:13 host.local echo[29756]: /etc/letsencrypt/aws_creds_prod.ini` in the journal.

What am I overlooking? Why does the environment variable (which is obviously being set correctly) appear to be unset to the process?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference if you remove the quotes around the value on the `Environment` line, does it?

Comment: @Göran Thank you very much, that was the missing piece in the puzzle. I have no idea **why** it would work without them, but the important thing is, it does apparently.

Comment: It works because the syntax for a systemd service file is not the same as the syntax for a POSIX shell such as bash. In fact, you don't need the quotes when running it from a shell prompt because the value of the env var does not contain any shell metachars (e.g., whitespace).

Comment: @Kurtis I am aware that systemd doesn't just take what's in the Environment statement and throws it in the bash. What puzzles me is that it does work in principle obviously (or echo would not work the way it does) but it doesn't work for certbot. How can an environment variable be set and not set at the same time?

Comment: It is set. Your echo command is effectively being run as you had typed this: `/bin/sh -c "/bin/echo $AWS_CONFIG_FILE"`. The shell is doing its usual quoted-string parsing and whitespace splitting of the command. Thus removing the single-quote chars from the output. Replace the `/bin/echo $AWS_CONFIG_FILE` with `/bin/echo "$AWS_CONFIG_FILE"` to see what I mean. The `certbot` command is retrieving the value of the env var directly from the environment and therefore getting the single-quotes as part of the pathname.

Comment: @Kurtis thanks for clarifying that. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for Environment in systemd can be one of the below 3 versions:

```sh
Environment="VAR1=word1 word2" VAR2=word3 "VAR3=$word 5 6"
```

This will produce 3 variables:

> **VAR1** with value **"word1 word2"**
>
> **VAR2** with value **"word3"**
>
> **VAR3** with value **"$word 5 6"**

So the syntax you used *(VAR='value')* is incorrect.

You can see more details [HERE](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment)